# Different userforms pop up depending on the selection made by the user in the first userform

Tags: vba

I'm trying to get one of 5 different user forms to open depending of the value of an input from the previous user from. I've tried putting the show command after an if statement with no success to date.

```
If Term_Long = Term_M1 Then
        If MtgType_1 = "variable" Then
            If Term_Long = 5 Then
                IntExp5y.Show
            ElseIf Term_Long = 4 Then
                IntExp4y.Show
            ElseIf Term_Long = 3 Then
                IntExp3y.Show
            ElseIf Term_Long = 2 Then
                IntExp2y.Show
            ElseIf Term_Long = 1 Then
                IntExp1y.Show
            End If
```

There is more to the code but this is one excerpt. I'm including this code within the code of the previous userform, after the button click sub

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your variables are correct, just use a `Select Case` instead.

```
   If  MtgType_1 = "variable" Then
        Select Case Term_Long 
          Case 5
            ' set variables in the IntExp5y form
            IntExp5y.Show
          Case 4
            ' set variables in the IntExp4y form
            IntExp4y.Show
          Case 3
            ' set variables in the IntExp3y form
            IntExp3y.Show
          Case 2
            ' set variables in the IntExp2y form
            IntExp2y.Show
          Case 1
            ' set variables in the IntExp1y form
            IntExp1y.Show
        End Select
   End If
```

Comment: Would I then need to add an if function to assign the various user inputs to cases?

Comment: That is not possible to answer without more information. However your question is confusing because you are using `Term_Long ` twice in your logic, and it's never going to be equal to 2 different things. I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify where to set variables.

Comment: So I'm comparing two mortgages. Term_M1 will be between 1 and 5 years, and Term_M2 will be between 1 and 5 years. Term_Long is set to be the length of the longer mortgage. I've only excerpted a portion of the code for this question

Comment: That does not really clarify anything for me. You asked how to use a variable to control which form shows, and that's the answer. How you go about creating all the other logic for your entire project is up to you.